# MySQL-Query - Can´t get the right result

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
Hello, you see here a screenshot of the table-structure, which I want to extract information from. It is a table from a messaging-system.

Two users, which write each other messages get a unique **msgconv** id.

Now, I would like to get the latest **msg** from each **msgconv** where a specific user is involved in, but the **msg** is not allowed to be deleted by the specific user.

This is my query at the moment:

```
SELECT v1.msgconv
     , v1.timesent
     , v1.msg
     , v1.msgfrom
     , v1.msgto
     , v1.msgdel_sender
     , v1.msgdel_receiver
  FROM msg v1
  LEFT 
  JOIN msg v2
    ON v1.msgconv = v2.msgconv 
   AND v1.timesent < v2.timesent
 WHERE v1.msgfrom = 69 
   AND v1.msgdel_sender = 0
    OR v1.msgto = 69
   AND v1.msgdel_receiver = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY timesent DESC
```

With this query I get 14 results and I don´t know why. What I should get is only the latest **msg** of each **msgconv**.

Can please someone help me with this, thank you

Comment: Format your code properly.  Then probably it will be easier to spot your error.

Comment: There's really no point outer joining tables from which you select no columns

Comment: `AND` has higher order of operation than `OR`.  If you just mash it up together like that, the `OR` will be the last one to be calculated.

Comment: `WHERE (v1.msgfrom = 69 AND v1.msgdel_sender = 0 AND v1.msgdel_receiver = 0)  OR v1.msgto = 69`  This is your `WHERE`.

Comment: Thank you, I format it better the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to get the latest msg from each msgconv where a specific user is involved

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the records to display:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY msgconv ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM msg m
    WHERE 
           ( msgfrom = 69 AND msgdel_sender = 0 )
        OR ( msgto = 69 AND msgdel_receiver = 0 )
) x
```

In earlier versions, you can use a `NOT EXISTS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM msg m
WHERE 
    ( 
           ( msgfrom = 69 AND msgdel_sender = 0 )
        OR ( msgto = 69 AND msgdel_receiver = 0 )
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM msg m1
        WHERE 
            (
                   ( m1.msgfrom = 69 AND m1.msgdel_sender = 0 )
                OR ( m1.msgto = 69 AND m1.msgdel_receiver = 0 )
            )
            AND m1.msgconv = m.msgconv 
            AND m1.timestamp > m.timestamp
    )
```

The query starts by selecting all records that belong to the relevant user. Then, the `NOT EXISTS` condition filters out every record but the latest in each group of record having the same `msgconv`.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. At the moment I don´t understand the query. :) I´m testing on MySQL 5.7 and when use your query I get and error back, at the "SELECT 1"- Line.

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen: sorry there was a typo on `EXITS` instead of `EXISTS`. Fixed just now.

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen: also I added a few explanations on how the query works.

Comment: Okay... Thank you. First i need to read in what "Exists" does, but there is one more question. I don´t get how SQL knows, that it has to give the latest message back. You set m1.timestamp > m.timestamp. How I would understand it, the query should give nothing back.. because m1.timestamp can´t be greater than m.timestamp.

Comment: @stefanhalbeisen: yes, this subquery should return nothing, this is why it is wrapped in a `NOT EXISTS` condition. Are you able to test the query against your dataset to check if it produces the expected result?

Comment: I tryed it now and it works. Thank you... - still wraping my head around it..:D